# js script only work for one element, only the first one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, checkbox

I have multiple checkbox elements on my page, whenever someone clicks on each of them, their color and text are changed, I was able to do that with CSS, but I wanted to change the icon in the checkbox button also, So I Use javascript in my HTML code but when I run the script it only works for one element, only the first one, so that means the icon only change for the first checkbox button but it is not working for all the other button, I tried to give all my checkbox button unique ID but I still have the same issue

This is checkbox 1 and 2 when not selected

[image]

This is checkbox 1 and 2 when selected

[image]

Here's the script I run to do that:

Ps: I use this script for all the other checkbox buttons, I already tried to change the id of the buttons to match HTML and the script id but still working only for the first one.

```js
  document.getElementById ('checkbox').addEventListener ('click', function (ev) {
    document.getElementById('icon').classList[ ev.target.checked ? 'add' : 'remove'] ('fa-circle-check');
  }, false);
```

UPDATE

I've read all your answers guys but none of them seems to solve my problem.
Please, kindly get a look at the full code here: https://codepen.io/edengandhi/pen/BaJoJYY

Comment: I'm guessing you have more than one element with the same ID?  IDs must be unique, getElementById will only find the first one.

Comment: I already tried to give each of my elements a unique id, here you can get a look at the full code for one element https://codepen.io/edengandhi/pen/BaJoJYY

Comment: There's only one in that pen, so no way to tell what's duplicated

Comment: You've tagged [tag:jquery] but don't have any jquery, so it's unclear if a jquery solution is suitable.  Give how short it is, it's worth providing:  `$(".checkbox").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("label").find(".icon").toggleClass("fa-circle-check");
});`  https://jsfiddle.net/9xcd2413/

Comment: Unfortunately, none of your answers seems not to solve my problem guys, here's the full code with multiple buttons: https://codepen.io/edengandhi/pen/BaJoJYY

Comment: First, your codepen has multiple `head` and `body` tags - there should only be one of these.  2nd code provided in comment above works fine (change id= to class= and appropriate selector)  https://jsfiddle.net/5v7ywm8d/  (also works with multiple head/body https://jsfiddle.net/5v7ywm8d/1/)

Comment: You haven't confirmed if [tag:jquery] solution is suitable or if you tagged it incorrectly.  Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, it would be welcome but It didn't work when I tried

Answer (score 2):

Do **NOT** use the same ID on multiple elements. It will only return the first one it finds. You should be setting multiple items with the class instead. You can then do.

`document.getElementByClassName('YourClassNameHere)`

or

`document.querySelectorAll('.YourClassNameHere')` *** NOTE the `.`... You will need `.` for the determining a class. `#` would determine for an ID.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer seems not to solve my problem, here's the full code here: https://codepen.io/edengandhi/pen/BaJoJYY

Answer (score 1):

```js
  document.getElementById ('checkbox').addEventListener ('click', function (ev) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('icon').classList[ ev.target.checked ? 'add' : 'remove'] ('fa-circle-check');
  }, false);
```

getElementsByClassName('icon') will select all classes that have that value.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer seems not to solve my problem, here's the full code here: https://codepen.io/edengandhi/pen/BaJoJYY

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` will only return the first element with the specified id, therefore giving multiple elements the same id won't help.
I suggest to check out `document.getElementsByClassName` providing the check boxes the same class instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer seems not to solve my problem, here's the full code here: https://codepen.io/edengandhi/pen/BaJoJYY

Answer (score -1):

you can use this but it this method returns a nodelist so you'd have to use a loop to add event listener to each of the checkboxes:

```
//if you're using class selector
 document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');

//if you're using id selector
 document.querySelectorAll('#checkbox')
```